# How to add only missing parameters to config file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am working with OpenWRT config file. One of my config file is like,

File 1:

```
config wifi1
 option enable  '1'
 option status ''
 option ssid ''
```

File 2:

```
config wifi1
  option enable '1'
  option status ''
  option ssid 'Primary5G'
  option password '12345678'
```

File1 is my default file, File2 is runtime generated file. In case if we add more parameters to File1.
For example,

File1 Modified,

```
config wifi1
  option enable '1'
  option status ''
  option ssid ''
  option wps '1'
```

I need to merge these files, copy the missing parameters content into File2, without overwriting the existing modified parameters.
So the File2 should be like,

```
config wifi1
  option enable '1'
  option status ''
  option ssid 'Primary5G'
  option password '12345678'
  option wps '1'
```

I need to do this shell script for merging the content.
I tried to use diff and patch for obtaining the output required.

I tried with below commands,

```
diff file1 file2 > diffs
```

This diffs has all the modifications, which I don't require.
If this could have worked, thought of applying this patch using,

```
patch -i diffs file2
```

But it is overwriting the existing parameters as well. And I can't use pattern because we have have multiple parameters going forward.
Any help?

Sample file will be like,

```
# uci configuration file2

config local
  option enable '1'
  option interface eth0
  option logging_level '3'

config server
  option https_enable '0'

config device
  option serial_number 123456

config notifications
  list active '1'

config interface
  option active '1'

# uci configuration file1

config local
  option enable '1'
  option interface eth0
  option logging_level '3'

config server
  option https_enable '0'

config device
  option serial_number 123456
  option host 'Dell'

config notifications
  list active '0'
```

Expected output,

```
# uci configuration file2

config local
  option enable '1'
  option interface eth0
  option logging_level '3'

config server
  option https_enable '0'

config device
  option serial_number 123456
  option host 'Dell'

config notifications
  list active '1'

config interface
  option active '1'
```

Comment: is there always only one "paragraph" that begins with `config wifi1`, or do these files contain other things?

Comment: It contains other sections as well and there could be changes to those sections as well.

Comment: Then shell is not the right tool for this, its going to be overcomplicated comparing to e.g. Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `gnu awk` script:

```sh
cat comb.awk
```

Use it as:

```sh
awk -f comb.awk file1 file2

$1 == "config" {             # when line starts with config
   cfg = $2                  # save 2nd field in cfg variable
}
NR == FNR {                  # while processing first file
   map[cfg][$2] = $0         # save [cfg][2nd file] in an array map
   next                      # move to next record
}
{                            # while processing second file
   delete map[cfg][$2]       # delete all matching entries from map
}
$1 == "config" {             # when line starts with config
   if (pcfg && pcfg in map) {
      for (i in map[pcfg])   # loop though remaining entries in map 
         print map[pcfg][i]  # print it
      print ""               # print a blank line
   }
   pcfg = cfg                # save current cfg in pcfg 
}
NF > 0;                      # print each non-empty line from second file 
END {                        # END block 
   if (pcfg in map)
      for (i in map[pcfg])   # loop though remaining entries in map 
         print map[pcfg][i]  # print it
}
```

```sh
# uci configuration
config local
    option enable '1'
    option interface eth0
    option logging_level '3'

config server
    option https_enable '0'

config device
    option serial_number 123456
    option host 'Dell'

config notifications
    list active '1'

config backup
    option active '1'
```